# DateTime where parameters in a Entity Data Source

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I want to filter in an `Entity Framework Query` that notes the date of writing, to do so I wrote this code, but I am experiencing the finding errors;

```
Dim stringa_where as String
Dim data_temp As String = giorno & "/" & mese & "/" & anno & " 00:00:00"
stringa_where = "it.data_nota=" & data_temp
EntityDataSource_note.Where = stringa_where
EntityDataSource_note.DataBind()
ListView_note.DataSource = EntityDataSource_note
ListView_note.DataBind()
ListView_note.Visible = True
```

When I arrived at the `ListView_note.DataBind()` code - I get this:

*The query syntax is not valid. Near term '00 ', line 6, column 27.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the quotes surrounding your date:

Try: `stringa_where = "it.data_nota='" & data_temp & "'"`

OK - plan B. Try:

```
EntityDataSource_note.Where = "it.data_nota = @param1"
// alternative when < is required:
// EntityDataSource_note.Where = "it.data_nota < @param1"
EntityDataSource_note.WhereParameters.Add("param1", TypeCode.DateTime, new DateTime(anno, mese, giorno).ToString())
EntityDataSource_note.DataBind()
ListView_note.DataSource = EntityDataSource_note
ListView_note.DataBind()
ListView_note.Visible = True
```

Comment: Hi, i try your solution and i try also 
stringa_where = "it.data_nota='" & Convert.ToDateTime(data_temp) & "'"
But I obtain

The argument types 'Edm.DateTime' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation.

Comment: ok, i try the plan B, the databind is ok but i obtain this error: "A property named 'it.data_nota' does not exist in metadata for entity type 'antiriciclaggio.note_pratica'".
But in antiriciclaggio.note_pratica I have this property

Comment: Where is the error thrown? Can you post your client side code for the ListView? If you have a field bound to the property make sure you drop the alias ie: `<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Data Nota"  DataField="data_nota"  SortExpression="data_nota"></asp:BoundField>`

Comment: I solved it, sorry! In my parameters I wrote data_ntoa instead of data_nota. By the way I have another question: In addWhereParameter can I add a clause as : "parameter < value"

Comment: I don't see why not. Try the version of the code in the comment of my edited answer above. (NB - I've re-named the parameter to "param1")